# NCurses with Arrow Keys Plus Modifiers

Tags: linux, ncurses, arrow-keys, modifier

I'm having trouble detecting arrow key presses with and without the SHIFT and CTRL modifiers pressed.

I have the following test code:

```
WINDOW * mainwin = initscr();
keypad(mainwin, TRUE);
int c = wgetch(mainwin);
```

This successfully returns different values for 'c' when the arrow keys - with modifiers - are pressed, and the terminal's TERM setting is set to **'xterm'**. It does not work when the terminal's TERM setting is set to **'linux'**. All I get for 'c' is 27 with either shift or ctrl pressed.

I would like it to work using the linux terminal type. Any suggestions?

Comment: The TERM setting must match the terminal you are running in.  "linux" won't work in an xterm only on the linux console.

Answer (score 5):

The Linux console is not able to represent modified cursor keys at all. You cannot detect the <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> state on this console, because it is not transmitted.

On a genuine xterm or sufficiently compatible clone (and most are these days), you can detect it, but it's an ability sufficiently new that `ncurses` doesn't understand it and gets confused by the extended escape sequence generated.

For that case I wrote a [keyboard input handling library](http://www.leonerd.org.uk/code/libtermkey/) specifically designed to handle modern terminal abilities; among them being extended key support.

You may try using that instead of `curses`'s `getch()`.